Change Multi Line Editing KeyBind Alt + Left Click Visual Studio
I'm talking about doing this:

I want to change the Alt + Left Click shortcut in Visual Studio.
I don't know how to search with a KeyBind (and this Is it possible to search for keyboard shortcuts by a keybind (Visual Studio 2017) works for like Ctrl C but not for Alt + Left click).
I don't know the name of that keybind.
This is not a duplicate of Multi-line Editing in Visual Studio because they explain how to achieve that behaviour but not how to modify it.

if you want to change the key binding, you can do it via the Command Palette. The command is called 'Add Selection to Next Find Match', and in my case, it is currently bound to Ctrl + D . 

How do open the command palette in Visual studio. I thought that was a Visual Studio Code thing.

You can open the Command Palette using the shortcut Ctrl + Shift + P, or by navigating to the View option in the navbar, where you will find an option to open the Command Palette.

None of those work in Visual Studio, they only work in Visual Studio Code, I'm confused
